# Do I need to "Hold RESET while you turn POWER off!" on the NES Mini version of Final Fantasy?

Tags: final-fantasy, nes-classic-mini

Final Fantasy still warns me to *"Hold RESET while you turn POWER off!"*

Do I have to do this on the NES classic edition?

[image: Saving at the inn]

Comment: [**Related**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229723/why-is-it-needed-to-hold-reset-when-powering-off-the-nes?rq=1). I'm guessing that holding the RESET button is no longer necessary with the NES Mini.

Comment: I'm guessing the NES Classic Mini is...Nintendo's version of RetroPie

Comment: There's just no point of trying to go into the game to remove this message.  The man power required is going to be huge.  There is probably nobody employed by Nintendo that even knows how to code in whatever it is they used originally.  We're talking about a THIRTY year old game.

Answer (score 10):

No.

The NES classic is a single board computer that is emulating a NES and does not need to go into a low power state.

Nintendo presents the titles in their original format. Fortunately, it's not on the original hardware and no longer requires these certain steps to ensure data capture.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can hold reset before turning the power off there is no need to. Your game is saved once that message pops up. However, hitting reset on the mini has something going for it that the original NES didn't. By hitting reset, you actually create a temporary save at the exact same location in the game as when you left it.

This is important for Final Fantasy 1, because enemy encounters are always in a set path -- by resetting you restart this path. So if you want to run the full game without ever stopping, but you need to stop because sleep/food/just a break, you can keep the same game going by using the temp save feature. When you return, you can  fight your next battle as though you'd never left.